# Continuous Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Is there something like a K-S test, but using an integral instead of a supremum?

My thinking is that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|F(x) - G(x)|dx$, where $F$ and $G$ are CDFs, will approximate zero if they are the same distribution, and will increase as the distributions diverge (in any manner - non-parametric?). No idea what that variable would look like, though.

The K-S test seems problematic to me because with small sample sizes, noise can have large effects. By using all the data, instead of just the largest difference, some of the effect of that noise can perhaps be removed.

Comment: The integral is not invariant to monotonic transformations (so you lose the nonparametric feature).  If you apply the PIT (so you're always testing uniformity, restoring it to be nonparametric) then your integral corresponds to the Cramer-von Mises, I believe.

Comment: @Glen_b: what is PIT? I was wondering whether Cramér-von Mises was what I was talking about - I stumbled across it just after asking the question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform

Comment: Thanks Nick, added it to the [wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIT_%28disambiguation%29) :)

Comment: Apologies for the abbreviation; it occurred to me a short while ago that I should come back and mention what that was, but @NickCox is fortunately there first. [I recall asking *exactly* your question about the integral as a stats student many years ago.] ... The Anderson-Darling is one of the most common choices; it has excellent power in a wide range of situations. But I agree with the advice to consider QQplots

Comment: Just to double check: if you're estimating parameters, none of K-S, C-vM, A-D have the required null distributions.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed. Check out Anderson-Darling, Cramér-von Mises tests, etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test is a start.

All these tests seem problematic to me for other reasons, not least because they don't tell you directly what is wrong. Increasingly with bigger datasets they reject hypotheses that are practically acceptable on the basis of statistically significant but practically insignificant deviations from what distribution is being fitted.

Quantile-quantile plots are a more practical technology.

Comment: You know, I actually used QQ plots on this data, a few months ago... didn't even think about it while writing this question. I'll have to go back and have another look at it. It would be nice to get a simple statistic out of it though - I was thinking something along the lines of a linear OLS fit to the QQ-plot, but my statistical experience is minimal, and I wasn't sure how valid that would be.

Comment: Complicated territory, but if you want or need a test, go with the existing machinery; don't invent a new procedure ad hoc. (For example, successive quantiles are necessarily dependent.) Naturally, almost nothing is guaranteed to work well with small samples.

Comment: Extra: The way that K-S works lends itself to criticism that it is _insensitive_ in the tails, where we should care most about being right and _unduly sensitive_ in the middles of distributions, where bad behaviour bites us less. Think of it this way: even the most outrageous outlier contributes just 1/$n$ to the CDF. See Rupert G. Miller, Beyond ANOVA, Wiley 1986/Chapman and Hall 1997 for this line.

Comment: @naught101 You're not too far off another test; in the normal case, the squared correlation in a QQplot is basically a Shapiro-Francia test (related to the Shapiro-Wilk). It won't be distribution-free, though, you'll have to get a new null distribution for every distribution you test (aside location-scale transformations). (Simulation may be required.)